# Using ValidateSet with functions or List

Tags: powershell, function, validateset

I'm trying to do something like this.
The Get-SomeOtherParameter returns a system.Array type list from a database.

I don't want to hardcode my ValidateSet in case the list changes overTime in the database

```sh
function Get-SomeItems { 
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet(Get-SomeOtherParameter)] 
        [string]$filter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet('abc', 'def', 'ghi')] 
        [String]$filter2
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Start-Automating's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73819326/45375) by **spelling out** the 
[`[ValidateScript({ ... }]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) and [`[ArgumentCompleter({ ... })`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) approaches:

```bash
# Function that returns the valid values for the -filter parameter below.
function Get-ValidFilterValues { 
  # Sample, hard-coded values. This is where your database lookup would happen.
  'foo', 'bar'
}

function Get-SomeItems {
  param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [ValidateScript({
        $validValues = Get-ValidFilterValues
        if ($_ -in $validValues) { return $true } # OK
        throw "'$_' is not a valid value. Use one of the following: '$($validValues -join ', ')'"
      })]
      [ArgumentCompleter({
        param($cmd, $param, $wordToComplete)
        (Get-ValidFilterValues) -like "$wordToComplete*" 
      })]      
      [string]$filter,

      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [ValidateSet('abc', 'def', 'ghi')] 
      [String]$filter2
  )

  $filter, $filter2 # sample output.

}
```

---

A **simpler *PowerShell (Core) 7+* alternative** is to implement validation via a custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) that implements the **[`System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator) interface**, which automatically *also* provides tab-completion:

```bash
# Custom class that implements the IValidateSetValuesGenerator interface 
# in order to return the valid values for the -filter parameter below.
class ValidFilterValues : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator { 
  [string[]] GetValidValues() { 
    # Sample, hard-coded values. This is where your database lookup would happen.
    return 'foo', 'bar'
  }
}

function Get-SomeItems {
  param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [ValidateSet([ValidFilterValues])] # Pass the custom class defined above.
      [string]$filter,

      [Parameter(Mandatory)]
      [ValidateSet('abc', 'def', 'ghi')] 
      [String]$filter2
  )

  $filter, $filter2 # sample output.

}
```

Comment: Good point, @Start-Automating; please see my update (I've decided to spell out the `[ArgumentCompleter]` solution too, while I'm at it).

Comment: cool and all, except for it only being on 7.  I didn't get too far into it for this answer, but I also build this whole transpiler for PowerShell, and can do scenarios like this without too much hassle in a way that works on multiple PowerShell versions.

Comment: Already did one for build-time defined aliases:

https://github.com/StartAutomating/PipeScript/blob/main/Transpilers/Parameters/Aliases.psx.ps1

Answer (score 2):

There's two aspects to what you're trying to do:

1. Making sure the parameter validation is correct
2. Making the PowerShell experience around it "good" (aka supporting tab completion).

#### Parameter Validation :

As you might have already noticed [ValidateSet] is a hard-coded list.  It's not *really* possible to soft code this (it *is* possible to dynamically build your script every time using some other modules, lemme know if you want more of an explainer for this).

To make the Validation work without `[ValidateSet]`, I'd suggest `[ValidateScript({})]`.  `[ValidateScript]` will run whatever script is in ValidateScript to ensure the script is valid.  If the [ValidateScript()] throws, the user will see that message when they pass an invalid value in.

#### Tab-Completion :

To make it feel easy, you'll also want to add support for tab completion.

This is fairly straightforward using the [`[ArgumentCompleter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_argument_completion?view=powershell-7.2#argumentcompleter-attribute) attribute.

Here's an example copied / pasted from a module called [LightScript](https://github.com/StartAutomating/LightScript/blob/main/Set-NanoLeaf.ps1#L116-L131)

```
[ArgumentCompleter({
        param ( $commandName,
            $parameterName,
            $wordToComplete,
            $commandAst,
            $fakeBoundParameters )
        $effectNames = @(Get-NanoLeaf -ListEffectName | 
            Select-Object -Unique) 
        if ($wordToComplete) {        
            $toComplete = $wordToComplete -replace "^'" -replace "'$"
            return @($effectNames -like "$toComplete*" -replace '^', "'" -replace '$',"'")
        } else {
            return @($effectNames -replace '^', "'" -replace '$',"'")
        }
    })]
```

This ArgumentCompleter does a few things:

1. Calls some other command to get a list of effects
2. If $wordToComplete was passed, finds all potential completions (while stripping off whitespace and enclosing in quotes)
3. If $WordToComplete was not passed, puts each potential completion in quotes

Basically, all you should need to change are the command names / variables to make this work.

Hope this Helps